# What is prevObject and why is my selector returning that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

I'm trying to obtain the top from an element but I'm getting this error, what does it mean and how do I get rid of it?

```
$(".hover").offset().top

>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

$(".hover")

[div.hover, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: ".hover", jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function…]
[prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: ".hover", jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function…]
```

This happens inside the drop event of jqueryui when I try to drop it into a nested droppable.

```
$.fn.makeDroppable = function(){
    $(this).droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            console.log($(".hover"));
            console.log($(".hover").offset().top);
            $(".hover").makeDroppable().removeClass("hover");
        },
        over: function(event, ui) {
            $("<div>").addClass("hover").appendTo(this);
        }
    });
}
$(".container").makeDroppable();

<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: it is because there is no element with class `myelement` in your page

Comment: @ArunPJohny There is, $(".hover") returns the element and prevObject which is not allowing me to use the top value.

Comment: You don't need to worry about `prevObject`. It's used for internal purposes. Your DOM selection is finding `0` elements.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that now, apparently the problem is caused by the nested droppables event being called. Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

jQuery returns prevObject if the DOM does not have the element for which jQuery is being run. You might see the element in your source at the run-time however, it is not not bound to the DOM and therefore, it shows prevObject. Try checking your js file again or else paste the code here.

Answer (score 15):

Although the error is not related to `prevObject`, I will explain it since it's a question in the title.

**jQuery .end()**

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

To return its previous state, jQuery returns `prevObject` which contains selected elements before filtering operation, such as `.find()`, `.filter()` and `.children()`, is applied.

**Example**

```
$('#target').append($('div').find('input').remove().end());
```

`$('div')` will select all div elements. --- **(*1)**

Then, `$('div').find('input').remove()` will select all input elements inside the selected div elements and delete these input elements.

After that, `$('div').find('input').remove().end()` will return the elements before `.find('input')` is called. Therefore, it will return all div elements same as in **(*1)** except that all input elements inside divs are removed.
The returned elements are stored in `prevObject`.

Finally, the returned elements **(*1)** are appended to `#target`.

---

`.end()`'s documentation: https://api.jquery.com/end/